# Android Studio App wont run, says "Error In Network Connection"

Tags: java, android

when ever I try to login, register, change password or reset password the app just says `Error In Network Connection`.

I am using strong internet connection, could you please advise as I have tried to on `WI-FI` and `4G`, however it still says the same error. I am using Wamp server to connect to phpMyAdmin database. Please could you help and advise.

**Login. Java File**

```
public class Login extends Activity {

    Button BtnLogin;
    Button Btnregister;
    Button passreset;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    private TextView loginErrorMsg;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        Btnregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);
       BtnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        passreset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.passres);

        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);

        passreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PasswordReset.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }});


        Btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Register.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }});

/**
 * Login button click event
 * A Toast is set to alert when the Email and Password field is empty
 **/
        BtnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                if ((!inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) && (!inputPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    NetAsync(view);
                } else if ((!inputEmail.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Password field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if ((!inputPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Email field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Email and Password field are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working.
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
         **/
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){



            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessLogin().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                loginErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone.
     **/
    private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                        /**
                         * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
                         **/
                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         *If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel.
                         **/
                        Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                        upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(upanel);
                        /**
                         * Close Login Screen
                         **/
                        finish();
                    }else{

                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }
}
```

**Register.java File**

```
public class Register extends Activity {


    /**
     *  JSON Response node names.
     **/


    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

    /**
     * Defining layout items.
     **/

    EditText inputFirstName;
    EditText inputLastName;
    EditText inputUsername;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        /**
         * Defining all layout items
         **/
        inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);



/**
 * Button which Switches back to the login screen on clicked
 **/

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologin);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        /**
         * Register Button click event.
         * A Toast is set to alert when the fields are empty.
         * Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
         **/

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                        NetAsync(view);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


/**
 * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
 **/
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessRegister().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }





    private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        /**
         * Defining Process dialog
         **/
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
            fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
            lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

            return json;


        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            /**
             * Checks for success message.
             **/
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        /**
                         * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                         **/

                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                         * Launch Registered screen
                         **/

                        Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                        /**
                         * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                         **/
                        registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(registered);


                        finish();
                    }

                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                    }

                }


                else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


            }
        }}
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }}
```

**manifest.xml file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.brad.visor" >

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Register">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Registered">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PasswordReset">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangePassword">
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Allow to connect with internet and to know the current network state-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


</manifest>
```

**Error Log :**

```
   06-25 20:08:48.881  23391-23391/com.brad.visor E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == nul

    06-25 20:35:21.853  23391-23391/com.brad.visor E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == nul

06-25 20:37:15.648    2183-2183/com.brad.visor E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
06-25 20:37:15.648    2183-2183/com.brad.visor E/Zygote﹕ v2
06-25 20:37:15.668    2183-2183/com.brad.visor E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
06-25 20:37:56.218    2183-2183/com.brad.visor E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

06-25 20:40:25.258     930-1128/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source 10014 txSuccessRate=1.50 rxSuccessRate=1.50 targetRoamBSSID=c4:04:15:c1:13:70 RSSI=-40
06-25 20:40:25.258     930-1128/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ [1,435,261,225,273 ms] noteScanStartWorkSource{10073} uid 10014
06-25 20:40:25.418     930-1429/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_ENGINE_STATE_IND_V02
06-25 20:40:25.818     930-1050/? E/PowerManagerService﹕ handleSandman : startDreaming, but isDreaming false

06-25 21:15:39.708     930-1128/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source 10014 txSuccessRate=4.63 rxSuccessRate=2.62 targetRoamBSSID=c4:04:15:c1:13:70 RSSI=-45
06-25 21:15:39.718     930-1128/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ [1,435,263,339,725 ms] noteScanStartWorkSource{10014} uid 10014
06-25 21:15:41.838      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-25 21:15:43.638     930-1128/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ [1,435,263,343,645 ms] noteScanEnd WorkSource{10014}
06-25 21:15:43.678     930-1128/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ wifi setScanResults statecom.android.server.wifi.WifiStateMachine$ConnectedState@550587e sup_state=COMPLETED debouncing=false
06-25 21:15:43.818      930-930/? E/LocSvc_flp﹕ I/===> int flp_inject_location(FlpLocation*) line 222
06-25 21:15:43.818     930-1419/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalRespCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientRespIndUnionType, void*) line 125 QMI_LOC_INJECT_POSITION_REQ_V02
06-25 21:15:44.838      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
```

Comment: That 'CatLog error' is in fact not an error at all...

Comment: well that is all the errors which I get.

Comment: what is the problem do u think I will need to try it on another device as people on google says that this error only happens on samsung devices.

Comment: Debug it and check the values of all the variables in the doInBackground method to see if ANY of them are null.

Comment: it says Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

Comment: That's not very useful information... Add some breakpoints

Comment: i have tried however it just does not give any error, my wamp server is connected and i have three php files in www file, please advise?.

Comment: still cant find no errors. what shall I do?.

Comment: can anyone please help me with this issue I am currently having.